# MacOS Automator impact maven on Jenkins job

Tags: macos, maven, jenkins, automator

We have macOS machine as a slave for Jenkins.
All code are executed on macOS machine.

After restarting macOS I have to reconnect slave manually.
So I created created a app with Automator and put it into lauch applications after login for my user.
Automator app is ash script like:

```
java -jar /selenium/slave.jar -jnlpUrl
http://1.2.3.4:4444/computer/macOS/slave-agent.jnlp -secret
0b149c641804f1424dsd998980sasd90asd8as73baa9f3f21c21e06d7681a6f6876ed
```

When I restart macOS the slave get up automatically,
BUT now I start getting build failures. Jenkins could not identify Maven anymore:

```
00:41:29 + mvn -v
00:41:29 /var/folders/88/6yf63sjn4r9_lzfld6m22fr80000gq/T/hudson5948404320742882477.sh: line 13: mvn: command not found
```

Looking forward for any comments on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell script is excuted as different process which doesn't have all the correct environment properties setup.

You definitely need to add maven path to the `PATH` variable, and probably a bunch of others, into your script.

Example

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/mvn:$PATH
java -jar /selenium/slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://1.2.3.4:4444/computer/macOS/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 0b149c641804f1424dsd998980sasd90asd8as73baa9f3f21c21e06d7681a6f6876ed
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try it at work on Monday and reply to the thread about the results